# Song stops playing when adding to library (Apple Music)

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, macos, apple-music

In iTunes on my MacBook Pro, when I am listening to a song and click on the + to add it to my library, it stops playing.

I don't have the same issue on my iPhone. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong? I don't see any posts on here or elsewhere on the internet about this?

Is there a workaround?

- iTunes version 12.7.0.166
- macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: This bug has been around for at least for a year now, and still hasn't been fixed. It has nothing to do with you, Apple needs to fix this bug. (happening to me too, with at least a few hundred people on Apple forums)

Comment: Yes! every time, before only have to close app and reopen and done, but with the new update happens every time

Answer (score 4):

After looking around this is a known bug and there currently is no workaround.

On [this Apple Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7698620?) a lot of people are reporting it so you are not alone.